# Embed AGOL Web Map into website without making it public

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, limitations

I have a web map created in AGOL and I want it to embed it into my website, but in AGOL you can do it only if you make it public in advance including all Layers, which I don't want to do (because it´s not allowed from client).

Is there a workaround solution ?

Documentation:

1. *In Map Viewer Classic, open a saved map and click Share.*
2. **Verify that the map is shared with everyone (public)**.
3. *Click Embed in Website.
   If this option is not available, it means the map is not public and you
   cannot embed it. If you are the owner of the map, and your organization
   allows sharing outside the organization, you can change its status to
   public.*

Comment: What is this website you are creating? Will this be used and viewed by ONLY You?

Comment: no this website is public obviously. the thing is that in the web site you cannot download the layers whereas in AGOL yes and this is not allowed from the client

Comment: What happens if you try to embed the map using standard html and an iframe?

Comment: could you please explain what you mean with standard html ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to make the map visible to the public, then you need to make everything in the map public (obviously).

However, if you don't want the layers downloadable, then don't include the layers in the map directly.

Instead, create a basemap from an amalgamation of all the layers in a map tile package (or similar), and embed this basemap into your web page.  This way, they can view them map like an image, but not access any of the data used to generate the map image.

See:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-map-tile-package.htm

Comment: sounds interesting Idea, I am going to give it a try and of course let you know. Thank you.